# Create values for group - SAS

Tags: sas, grouping

```
data test;
input Index Indicator value FinalValue;
datalines;

1 0  5   21
1 1  21  21
2 1  0   0
3 0  4   7
3 1  7   7
3 0  8   7
3 0  2   7
4 1  1   1
4 0  4   1
;
run;
```

I have a data set with the first 3 columns. How do I get the 4th columns based on the indicators? For example, for the index, when the indicator =1, the value is 21, so I put 21 is the final values in all lines for index 1.

Comment: Do you have a set value for column 4 for all index values?  Is 21 for index = 1 a predetermined value or is it a calculated value.  Also, what code have you tried so far?

Comment: 21 is calculated based on the first 3 columns. because for account 1, when its indicator is 1, the value is 21, so we used 21 as its final value.

Comment: Value for fourth row (first one with INDEX=3) does not look right.  Should by 7 by your rules.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the SAS `Retain` Keyword.

You can do this in a data step; by Retaining the Value where indicator = 1.

Steps:

- Sort your data by Index and Indicator
- Group by the Index & Retain the Value where Indicator=1

Code:

```
/*Sort Data by Index and Indicator & remove the hardcodeed finalvalue*/
proc sort data=test (keep= Index Indicator value); 
by index descending indicator ;
run;

/*Retain the FinalValue*/
data want;
set test;
retain FinalValue;
keep Index Indicator value FinalValue;
if indicator =1 then do;FinalValue=value;end;
/*The If statement below will assign . to records that doesn't have an indicator value of 1*/
if  indicator ne 1 and FIRST.Index=1 then FinalValue=.;
by index;
run;
```

Output:

```
Index=1 Indicator=1 value=21 FinalValue=21 
Index=1 Indicator=0 value=5 FinalValue=21 
Index=2 Indicator=1 value=0 FinalValue=0 
Index=3 Indicator=1 value=7 FinalValue=7 
Index=3 Indicator=0 value=4 FinalValue=7 
Index=3 Indicator=0 value=8 FinalValue=7 
Index=3 Indicator=0 value=2 FinalValue=7 
Index=4 Indicator=1 value=1 FinalValue=1 
Index=4 Indicator=0 value=4 FinalValue=1
```

Comment: I tried the code to a much larger data set (with more columns). I get message: ERROR: BY variables are not properly sorted on data set WORK.TEST. Cannot figure out why.

Comment: Make sure the proc sort runs without errors and sorted by Index in ascending order then by Indicator in Descending order.

Answer (score 2):

Use proc sql by left join. Select value which indicator=1 and group by index, then left join with original dataset. It seemed that your first row of index=3 should be 7, not 0.

```
proc sql;
   select a.*,b.finalvalue from test a 
   left join (select *,value as finalvalue from test group by index having indicator=1) b
   on a.index=b.index;
quit;
```

Comment: The 4th column is the column I want to create. It doesn't exist in the original data set.

Answer (score 0):

This is rather old school but should be adequate.  I reckon you call it a self merge or something.

```
data test;
   input Index Indicator value;* FinalValue;
   datalines;
1 0  5   21
1 1  21  21
2 1  0   0
3 0  4   7
3 1  7   7
3 0  8   7
3 0  2   7
4 1  1   1
4 0  4   1
;;;;
   run;
data final;
   if 0 then set test;
   merge test(where=(indicator eq 1) rename=(value=FinalValue)) test;
   by index;
   run;
proc print;
   run;


                                      Final
Obs    Index    Indicator    value    Value

 1       1          0           5       21
 2       1          1          21       21
 3       2          1           0        0
 4       3          0           4        7
 5       3          1           7        7
 6       3          0           8        7
 7       3          0           2        7
 8       4          1           1        1
 9       4          0           4        1
```